# How does fork() function in gcc compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, fork, parent-child

I have a C program with fork() call in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main ( )
{
    fork () ;
    printf ( "\nHello" ) ;
    fork () ;
    printf ( "\nWorld" ) ;
}
```

This is the output I got on gcc:

```
Hello Hello World World World World
```

Shouldn't it be :

```
Hello Hello World World Hello Hello World World
```

Because of the following :

```
Line1: First fork creates a child process.
1.2: Prints 'Hello'
1.3:Creates a child process because of 2nd fork in it.
1.3.2:Prints 'Hello' and 'World'.
1.4:Prints 'World'.
Line2: Prints 'Hello'.
Line3: Second fork() creates child process
3.1:creates a child process
3.2: Prints 'Hello'
3.4: Prints 'World'
Line 4: Prints 'World'
```

This is how I think this program would work. Can you please explain where I went wrong. This is why I want to understand how the function works.

Note: I checked the man page but I don't understand much of it.

Also the numbers are the line numbers of main function. Ex: 1.2 corresponds to the second line of a child process created by the Line 1 fork() call of the main() and so on.

I am unable to figure out how it produces that particular output. So I want to understand, what happens during fork () is invoked in simple steps?

Comment: By the way, add `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf`, or the output may become more complicated to understand due to the C library buffering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So:

1. There's no solid guarantee which order things are going to happen in (that all depends on the scheduler), other than the first thing will definitely be "Hello" and the last thing will definitely be "World".
2. By the time you get to the "Hello" line there are two copies of the program going (one fork plus original), so "Hello" will print twice.  Each of those copies forks another copy, so by the time you get to "World" there are four copies, so "World" will print four times.
3. When you fork() a copy, it starts *right there*; it doesn't start from the beginning.

Comment: But I always get the same output. And if the fork creates a copy that starts right there, then should the output be : Hello World World Hello World World ???

Comment: @BharathYes I'm not surprised; the system is probably going to schedule the same events in the same order every time (ie every run of the program does the same thing, so it probably gets scheduled the same way every time). It would be really really really surprising for one thread to get too far ahead of the others (fork takes up some time, compared to printf), but theoretically one process could finish before another one gets to print anything.

Comment: So what you say is that since the threads are executed in parallel with one another they print 'Hello' and 'World' with a little bit of time difference. I understand it now. Thanks for explaining with patience.

Comment: @BharathYes and to answer the added question: Once you fork, you no longer have a linear path, but parallel paths.  The original and the first copy will both print "Hello" and "World"; the second and third copies will each print just "World" -- but those four processes are each separate processes, and you have no control over which order any of them will happen.  Nor must they run to completion before a new one takes over; they can be switched in and out of control at the discretion of the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

When you fork() a child, it starts right from the next line of code and it doesn't start from the beginning.

main():

```
Line1 Creates child one
Line2 prints "Hello"
Line3 Creates child two
Line4 prints "World"
```

child one:

```
Line2 prints "Hello"
Line3 Creates child three
Line4 prints "World"
```

child two:

```
Line4 prints "World"
```

child three:

```
Line4 prints "World"
```

Thus, one possible answer is

```
Hello Hello World World World World
```

from main, child one, main, child one, child two and child three respectively

However the order of execution may change(`Race Condition`)

Answer (score 1):

You can not be sure which process will carry on first, when the fork call is made. Hence there's no way to actually find out the correct order of the Output.

The only guarantee is that there will be an execution for all of the processes, forked child and parent.

Now after the first fork, there are two processes, hence you can be sure that atleast two `Hello` and two `World` will be printed. Although, after printing two `Hello`, there is another fork.

Now this fork will be executed by both the processes and hence you will have for processes in ready state now, and each on execution will print `World`. Hence that is why you see , in the final output, **two** `Hello` and **four** `World`